# Paragraph Tags removed when contents are only a shortcode

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I'm developing a plugin that given a shortcode with attributes will scan a json file and return the appropriate data etc.

Given code like this:

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>[environ data="day_max" format="long"]</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>[environ data="day_min"]</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Data is being returned like

`9.82°C at 12:49:59 AM 9.82°C`

without the paragraphs and bunched together. If I add any leading text the problem vanishes (see below).  If I place short codes within table cells it vanishes.  The issue only presents itself if the short code is alone in a paragraph.

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Test [environ data="day_max" format="long"]</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

returns

`<p>Test 9.82°C at 12:49:59 AM</p>`

I've looked at [Remove empty p-Tags in Shortcode content before non p-Tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331413/remove-empty-p-tags-in-shortcode-content-before-non-p-tags) and similar posts but they don't seem to address this issue.

My code is a `add_shortcode('environ', array(&$byteenviron ,'byteenviron_display_handler'));` function call to `byteenviron_display_handler` which processes the attributes and returns a string.

Comment: I don't currently have an answer to what's asked in the question, but why not just add the paragraph in your shortcode handler function? I.e. Add it conditionally - if there should be something *non-empty* to return, then include the paragraph tags; else, then return an empty string. So for example, `return $output ? "<p>$output</p>" : '';`.

Comment: .. and then use the [Shortcode block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/shortcode-block/) instead to add your shortcode.